# Get fields from nested DocumentReference item in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm in the process of writing an API using firebase functions: api is written in javascript.

In my firestore db, I have a user document that contains some nested fields. For example, my user doc has a field that looks roughly like this:

- profile

  - education

    - education1 --> degree: doc ref, date: timestamp, school: doc ref
    - education2 --> degree: doc ref, date: timestamp, school: doc ref

I cannot for the life of me access the degree object and get the properties out of it. Each user could have multiple education entries (for example, people who hold multiple degrees). I can't step into those education# maps and access the fields inside the document they are referring to.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share your code?

Comment: Is "profile" in your bullet list corresponding to the user doc? And what is the type of the "education" filed? An array? A map? Can you share a picture of your Firestore console, to show how the documents and fields are defined?

Comment: As far as I know they are all maps.  profile is a map, education is a map that lives inside of profile, and education items are also maps that live inside of education.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share a picture of your Firestore console, to show how the documents and fields are defined? It will allow to give a precise answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give a lot of details on your exact data model: which collection, which document, etc...

However, since in your comment above you say that "profile is a map, education is a map that lives inside of profile, and education items are also maps that live inside of education" the following should do the trick

```
  var docRef = firestore.collection('collectionId').doc('docID');

  docRef
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        const educationObj = doc.data().profile.education;
        const promises = [];
        Object.keys(educationObj).forEach(key => {
          promises.push(firestore.doc(educationObj[key].degree.path).get());
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log('No such document!');
        throw new Error('no doc');
      }
    })
    .then(results => {
      results.forEach(r => {
        console.log(r.data());
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error getting document:', error);
    });
```

---

The `degree` property contains a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference), therefore you need use the [`path`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#path) property in order to get the corresponding document.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out today. I was definitely being vague but I was looking for more of a generic answer, like this one. I'll give it a try and let you know what happens :)

Comment: @HaniHoney Hello, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hi Renaud, I'm sorry I never replied. I ended up not needing to do this, in the end, but I appreciate your help and I believe that it was the correct solution :)